# Reorder and Reshape elements in numpy ndarray

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape

I have a numpy ndarray returned by an external module. The shape of the array is (3,3,128). Basically a stack of 128 tiles, each tile being 3x3.

How do I reorder so that the shape becomes (128,3,3). this way it will easier to index by tile number. The final step is then to flatten to (128,9) so that each of the 128 tiles can be accessed easily as a 9 value vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use transpose with new array order specified, for example,

```
a = np.arange(0,3*3*128).reshape(3,3,128) 
a_reorder = a.transpose([2,0,1])
```

which you can check is correct by comparing all the tiles,

```
np.all([np.all(a[:,:,i]==a_reorder[i,:,:]) for i in range(128)])
```

and flatten with

```
a_flat = a_reorder.reshape(128,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reshape 3 * 3 * 128 to 128 * 3 * 3:

```
y = einops.rearrange(x, 'x y tile -> tile x y')
```

Or we can reshape directly to 128 * 9 in one operation

```
y = einops.rearrange(x, 'x y tile -> tile (x y)')
```